# angular7 input type file upload not working

Tags: angular, angular6, angular7

Present i'm working angular angular 7 input type="file" not working.

Angular6 its working fine.

angular 6 submit the input file type data

i will get field list like this

[image]

But angular 7 only get image path like this.

[image]

only i updated angular 6 to angular 7 i will get this error.
what is the issue i don't know.

*Thanks*,

Comment: please add your code also

Comment: code is much length i am using formcontrol name and submit get this type of data

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: sorry not a error. angular 6 form submit i will get fieldlist.And angular 7 only image path get,Like the above images

Comment: create one stackblitz

Comment: this is my stackblitz url (https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6cstnu?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts) after submit please see console

Comment: You should upate your question with your stackblitz link and update the title to include "ReactiveForm" term. For a quick workaround you can access the files list of your input by using the 'change' output : `<input #fileInput type="file" (change)="fileChange($event)>"` and then in your controller `fileChange(event) { const fileList = event.target.files }` or using a `@ViewChild('fileInput') fileInput => this.fileInput.nativeElement.files`. In this way you can still using your 'image' formControl for validation purpose and retrieve your file list on submit.

Answer (score 2):

I have a upload document section in my Angular app, here is working example:

**example.component.html**

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Select file to upload.</label>
    <input type="file" id="bannedList" (change)="onFileChange($event);" #fileInput>
</div>
</form>
<button type="button" (click)="onSubmit();" [disabled]="!fileInput.value" class="btn btn-success pull-right"><i class="fa fa-save fa-fw"></i> Upload File</button>
```

**example.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy, ElementRef, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup } from "@angular/forms";

...

export class exampleUploadComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  public form: FormGroup;
  @ViewChild('fileInput', { read: ElementRef }) private fileInput: ElementRef;

...

  createForm() {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      bannedList: null
    });
  }

  onFileChange(event) {
    this.uploadStatus = 0;
    if (event.target.files.length > 0) {
      let file = event.target.files[0];
      this.form.get('bannedList').setValue(file);
    }
  }

  private prepareSave(): any {
    let input = new FormData();
    input.append('bannedChequeCustomersFile', this.form.get('bannedList').value);
    return input;
  }

  onSubmit() {
    const formModel = this.prepareSave();
    this.uploadChequeSubscription = this.chequeOperationService.uploadBannedChequeList(formModel).subscribe(
      (res) => {
        console.log("res handler:", res);
      },
      (err) => {
        console.log("err handler:", err);
      }
    );
  }
```

I hope it will help, thanks.

Answer (score -1):

var selectedElement: File = (document.getElementById(id) as HTMLElement).files[0] as File;

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).