# TypeError: Cannot read property 'post' of undefined error on Angular 7 Upload file

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, upload, angular7

i'm new of Angular.
My target is do a single uploader zip file and put in on folder.
So my `html` code:

```
<div class="form-group">
          <label for="file">Choose File</label>
          <input type="file" id="file" (change)="handleFileInput($event.target.files)">
        </div>
```

My `component.ts` code:

```
handleFileInput(files: FileList) {
      this.fileToUpload = files.item(0);
      alert(this.fileToUpload.type + " " + this.fileToUpload.name + " " + this.fileToUpload.size / 1024);
      this.postFile(this.fileToUpload);
  }

  httpClient: any;
  postFile(fileToUpload: File): Observable<boolean> {
    const endpoint = 'your-destination-url';
    const formData: FormData = new FormData();
    formData.append('fileKey', fileToUpload, fileToUpload.name);
    return this.httpClient
      .post(endpoint, formData, { headers: "yourHeadersConfig" })
      .map(() => { return true; })
      .catch((e) => this.handleError(e));
}
  handleError(e: any): any {
    alert(e);
  }
```

on the handeFileInput i receive correctly all info about the file, the name the size ecc...
But when I start the method `postFile` i receive this error:

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'post' of undefined
>       at ListCertificatesComponent.push../src/app/list-certificates/list-certificates.component.ts.ListCertificatesComponent.postFile
>   (list-certificates.component.ts:43)
>       at ListCertificatesComponent.push../src/app/list-certificates/list-certificates.component.ts.ListCertificatesComponent.handleFileInput
>   (list-certificates.component.ts:34)
>       at Object.eval [as handleEvent] (ListCertificatesComponent.html:46)
>       at handleEvent (core.js:21673)
>       at callWithDebugContext (core.js:22767)
>       at Object.debugHandleEvent [as handleEvent] (core.js:22470)
>       at dispatchEvent (core.js:19122)
>       at core.js:19569
>       at HTMLInputElement. (platform-browser.js:993)
>       at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask
>   (zone.js:421)

I've trying to insert but without success:

```
import { Http} from '@angular/http';
```

Thanks for help

Comment: Here is working example, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53493693/angular7-input-type-file-upload-not-working/53758764#53758764

Comment: You never initialise your `httpClient` variable

Answer (score 0):

inject the `HttpClient` to the constructor instead of using `httpClient: any;`

```
import { HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import {map, catchError} from 'rxjs/Operators';

constructor(
    private httpClient: HttpClient, 
)
postFile(fileToUpload: File): Observable<boolean> {

  return this.httpClient
    .post(endpoint, formData, { headers: "yourHeadersConfig" })
    .pipe (
       map(() => { return true; })
       catchError((e) => this.handleError(e))
     );

}
```

Comment: cannot find name Http....are you sure this solution works on angular 7 ?

Comment: Sorry use the `HttpClient`

Comment: Last question, on the headers, do you tell me how to complete ? With what ? Thansk

Comment: @Mr.Developer : `HttpClient` methods auto complete

Comment: Create `nrew HttpHeaders`. check this https://stackblitz.com/angular/ooqemvjyqkb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fheroes%2Fheroes.service.ts

Comment: I still have problem on .map.. why ?? There's no method map

Answer (score 0):

You are using `HttpClient` the wrong way.

[Angular - HttpClientModule](https://angular.io/guide/http)

First you will need to import `HttpClientModule` in `app.module.ts`.

```
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
```

You need to import and inject `HttpClient` in service.

```
import { HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';

constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {}

postFile(fileToUpload: File): Observable<boolean> {
  const endpoint = 'your-destination-url';
  const formData: FormData = new FormData();
  formData.append('fileKey', fileToUpload, fileToUpload.name);
    return this.httpClient
        .post(endpoint, formData, { headers: "yourHeadersConfig" })
        .subscribe((response: any) => { console.log('Response', response); })
        .catch((e) => this.handleError(e));
}
```

Please refer following link for more info.

[Angular - HttpClientModule](https://angular.io/guide/http)

Comment: Sorry but i continue to have error.. Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Observable<Object>', i've done what you did.

Comment: Sorry but i continue to have error.. Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Observable<Object>', i've done what you did.

Comment: Updated Answer. Please check.